# Remove User defined object from Java LinkedList Collection framework

Tags: java, collections

I want to remove user defined object from Java LinkedList Collection framework. Below code does not remove the object. What am I missing?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyObjectKeySearch {
    static class CMDTimeSlot{
        String comm;
        int orig;
        int prio;
        public  CMDTimeSlot(String comm,int orig,int prio){
            this.comm = comm;
            this.orig = orig;
            this.prio = prio;
        }

    }

public static void main(String a[]){
        List<CMDTimeSlot> cmdlist = new LinkedList<>();

        CMDTimeSlot one = new CMDTimeSlot("010D",2,2);
        CMDTimeSlot two = new CMDTimeSlot("0100",1,1);

        CMDTimeSlot three = new CMDTimeSlot("010C",3,3);

        cmdlist.add(one);
        cmdlist.add(two);
        cmdlist.add(three);

        for(CMDTimeSlot obj: cmdlist){
            System.out.println(obj.comm +" " + obj.orig +" "+obj.prio);
        }

        cmdlist.remove(new CMDTimeSlot("0100",1,1) );

        for(CMDTimeSlot obj: cmdlist){
            System.out.println(obj.comm +" " + obj.orig +" "+obj.prio);
        }
    }
}
```

## output::

> 010D 2 2 0100 1 1 010C 3 3
>
> 010D 2 2
>
> 0100 1 1 010C 3 3

Comment: You didn't implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`, so the `remove()` call is comparing object *identity*, not object values.

Comment: if i iterate through the linkedlist and remove the matching object then its work::for(CMDTimeSlot cmd: cmdlist){
            if(cmd.comm.equalsIgnoreCase("0100")){
                cmdlist.remove(cmd);
            }
        }

Comment: **Read the javadoc** of [`LinkedList.remove(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-): *removes the element with the lowest index `i` such that `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))` (if such an element exists).* As you can see, you need to implement [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) on your class `CMDTimeSlot` class for it to compare `comm` values.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Override `equals` and `hashcode` method using your member variables for class `CMDTimeSlot`.